# What causes WIA errors 0x8021006C, 0x8021006D, and 0x8021006E?

Tags: .net, wia

When trying to set WIA item/device properties I get this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8021006E): Exception from HRESULT: 0x8021006E
   at WIA.IProperty.get_SubTypeMin()
   ...
```

This is my code:

```
public void SetIntProperty(Item item, int propid, int value)
{
    foreach (Property prop in item.Properties)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyID == propid)
        {
            if (value < prop.SubTypeMin) {
                value = prop.SubTypeMin;
            }
            if (value > prop.SubTypeMax) {
                value = prop.SubTypeMax;
            }
            object objprop = value;
            prop.set_Value(ref objprop);
        }
    }
}
```

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Those errors are caused by trying to access [SubType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-related properties for a SubType that doesn't support them. You need to check the `prop.SubType` field first. You can only access:

- `prop.SubTypeMin`, `prop.SubTypeMax` and `prop.SubTypeStep` if `prop.SubType == WiaSubType.RangeSubType` (0x8021006E)
- `prop.SubTypeValues` if `prop.SubType == WiaSubType.ListSubType || prop.SubType == WiaSubType.FlagSubType` (0x8021006D)
- `prop.SubTypeDefault` if `prop.SubType != WiaSubType.UnspecifiedSubType` (0x8021006C)